# how can I autostart my app in android after reboot?

Tags: android, service, wakelock, autostart

I have used BootComplete and allow permission and it still cant autostart,then I try to use wake lock but it cannot work. Also, I try to make it as a service but the service does not pop up in my phone.Is there anything I missed?

```
       public class BootComplete extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

{
            // This is the Intent to deliver to our service.
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, AutoStartUp.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);

        }
    }

public class AutoStartUp extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // do something when the service is created
    }

}
```

In my manifest file:

```
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

 <service android:name=".SimpleWakefulReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.SimpleWakefulReceiver"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MainActivity$BootComplete"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".AutoStartUp">
        </service>
```

Comment: As of API 3.1, you need an `Activity` in your app to launch at least once after installation to bring it out of the _stopped_ state. Until then, your Receiver is not going to work. Also, your Receiver needs to be exported. That is, set the `exported` attribute to `true`, or just remove it.

Comment: yeah ur right mike; remove exported and enabled attribs; also when starting activities using receivers u need this flag; **intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);**

Answer (score 0):

Do whatever you intend in onReceive -

```
public class BootupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("BOOTUP", "received notification ......................");
    if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
    {
        Log.e("BOOTUP","RECEIVED BOOT NOTIFICATION ........");
        Intent start_service = new Intent(context,MainService.class);
        context.startService(start_service);
    }
}
```

in the Manifest add-

```
<receiver
        android:name=".AutoStart"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

add permission-

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Also you need to launch your application from activity atleast once and your  block should be outside  block in manifest